# How to install ubuntu on live USB stick that I booted from?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, live-usb, lubuntu

I have a old netbook with single USB port and broken harddrive. I've somehow aquired a 16gb lubuntu 15.10 willy live USB. I want to use this as primary OS on my netbook. Since I don't have access to another computer, I want to somehow manage to install lubuntu on very USB stick I booted live session from. Is there any way? My netbook have ram size of 1gb.

Comment: Did you flash the USB yourself? Do you know that you can make a certain portion of your bootable USB drive persist on boot, meaning save your files/progress between sessions?

Comment: No. Made by friend for me. He did not add that save to usb thing nor does he know how.

Comment: Does you netbook support CD? I'd recomment booting into live CD and install into the USB which is not terribly confusing. If not, You probably gonna have to partition your USB and install it on the partition while also live from the same usb. I'ven't done it, but think it's possible. Someone might give you more insight.

Comment: Here is the link which can be useful for you [Install Ubuntu onto a USB flash drive using the SAME flash drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520163/can-i-install-ubuntu-onto-a-usb-flash-drive-using-the-same-flash-drive)

Comment: Bibek_5, Netbooks usually don't have CD drive and mine as well.   Also the link given by Ang Red only explains about persistent mode, which is not helpful in my case